# How to change Hint (THintWindow) position?

Tags: delphi, tooltip

I made a textedit box on my form and made a Hint.
When, TextEdit occurs onExit event, It shows hint message.
It works.

But, It doesn't follow parent component when Application move or resize.
Even I set Hint's parent which is Form.

So, How I can move (or repaint) hint on my component?

Comment: Please explain how you implemented this window. Showing code would leave no room for doubt.

Comment: Normally when you move or resize the form, eg by mouse-dragging on the title bar or window borders, the hint would disappear. Please add code that shows what you're doing.

Comment: Obviously window parent is not the form. You can use WM_MOVING of the form to hide/show/move the top-level hint window.

Comment: The component should handle the `CM_HINTSHOW` message and customize the provided `THintInfo` record as needed, which includes positioning and even the classtype. Let the VCL manage the hint window, you just tell it what type of hint to show and where/when to show it.